# Why is PHP Mailer not always sending email?

Tags: php, mysql, email, phpmailer

We have a site with a form that when submitted, does the following (via the code below);

1. Sends a test email to myself BEFORE INSERTING INTO MYSQL just so i know php mailer is working, which it always does in all my tests
2. Then inserts all the data from the form into MYSQL (This always works too)
3. Send another email via PHP Mailer with all the info they submitted.  I want it in plain text (this works only about 80% of the time).

What's happening is, sometimes people submit and it does everything, but sometimes it only does steps 1 and 2.  So sometimes, something seems to be breaking somewhere.  I feel like it could be issues with certain punctuation, but not sure. Like in the $copy fields, people can enter whatever they want. Not sure if there are certain punctuations that could break the 2nd email process.

NOTE:  Every time someone submits, it does take them to the request-success.php page.  But it doesn't always send the email from Step 3.

If anyone sees areas of improvement, or things that are just wrong, please share.  This is driving me insane.

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    include_once("config.php");
    include_once("includes/functions.php");
    require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    //database configuration & connection (hiding for privacy purposes, but the database connections work fine so not relevant

    if ($_POST['submit']) {

        $type=$_POST['type'];

        $category= substr($type, 0, strpos($type, ' -'));
        $category= strtolower($category);
        $category= ucfirst($category);
        $need = substr($type, strpos($type, "-") + 1);    

        $subject="REQUEST for " . $type;
        $fullname= $_SESSION['google_data']['name'];
        $fromemail=$_SESSION['google_data']['email'];

        $brands=$_POST['brand'];

        $size=$_POST['size'];
        if ($size == "") {
            $size="n/a";
        }
        $bleed=$_POST['bleed'];
        if ($bleed =="no") {
            $bleedsize="n/a";
        } else {
            $bleedsize=$_POST['bleedsize'];
        }
        $filetype=$_POST['filetype'];
        if ($filetype=="") {
            $filetype="n/a";
        }
        $footerurl=$_POST['footer-url'];
        if ($footerurl=="") {
            $footerurl="n/a";
        }
        $footerphone=$_POST['footer-phone'];
        if ($footerphone=="") {
            $footerphone="n/a";
        }
        $copy=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['copy']);
        $copyforemail=$_POST['copy'];

        $approved=$_POST['approved'];
        $seo=$_POST['seo'];
        $proofread=$_POST['proofread'];
        $info=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['info']);
        $infoforemail=$_POST['info'];

        $priority=$_POST['priority'];
        $requestdate= date('Y-m-d');
        $duedate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $_POST['duedate'])));
        if ($duedate =="1969-12-31") {
        $duedate="0000-00-00";  
        }
        $timinginfo=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['timinginfo']);
        $timinginfoforemail=$_POST['timinginfo'];

        $communication=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['communication']);
        $communicationforemail=$_POST['communication'];

    //TEST EMAIL BEFORE INSERTING
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output
    /*
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = '';                // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
    */
    $mail->setFrom($fromemail, $fullname);
    $mail->addAddress('myemail@myemail.com', 'my name');     // Add recipients
    $mail->addReplyTo('myemail@myemail.com', 'my name');
    /*$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');


    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name*/
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = "Request coming for Creative Team";
    $mail->Body    = "Request coming";
    $mail->AltBody = "Request coming";

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
       //continue to insert
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO requests (firstname, lastname, email, picture, category, type, brand, size, bleed, bleedsize, filetype, footerurl, footerphone, copy, approved, proofread, seo, info, priority, requestdate, duedate, timinginfo, communication ) VALUES ('" . $_SESSION['google_data']['given_name'] . "', '" . $_SESSION['google_data']['family_name'] . "','" . $_SESSION['google_data']['email'] . "', '" . $_SESSION['google_data']['picture'] . "', '$category', '$need', '$brands', '$size', '$bleed', '$bleedsize', '$filetype', '$footerurl', '$footerphone', '$copy', '$approved', '$proofread', '$seo', '$info', '$priority', '$requestdate', '$duedate', '$timinginfo', '$communication')"; 

        $insertinfo = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if (!$insertinfo) {
        die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error($con));
        } else {    
        //Success, continue to email...
        }


    $plaintextversion= "
    $type

    BRAND: $brands


    SPECS

    SIZE:  $size

    BLEED:  $bleed

    BLEED SIZE:  $bleedsize

    FILE TYPE:  $filetype

    FOOTER URL:  $footerurl

    FOOTER PHONE:  $footerphone

    COPY:  $copyforemail

    COPY APPROVED?  $approved

    PROOFREAD?  $proofread

    ADDITIONAL INFO:  $infoforemail


    TIMING

    PRIORITY:  $priority

    REQUEST DATE:  $requestdate

    DESIRED DUE DATE:  $duedate

    TIMING INFO: $timinginfoforemail


    COMMUNICATION

    ADDITIONAL PEOPLE TO INCLUDE:  $communicationforemail";


    } else {
        header("Location:index.php");
    }

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output
    /*
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = '';                // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
    */
    $mail->setFrom($fromemail, $fullname);
    $mail->addAddress('someone@someone.com', 'someone');     // Add recipients
    $mail->addReplyTo('myemail@myemail.com', 'my name');
    /*$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');


    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name*/
    $mail->isHTML(false);                                  // Set email format to plain text since that is what Salesforce needs

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $plaintextversion;
    $mail->AltBody = $plaintextversion;

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        header("Location:request-success.php");
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your query is wide open to SQL injection attacks and could be the cause of your issues if you have quotes in your content. You're already using mysqli, so you should have prepared statements functionality available to you to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want plain-text only, call `isHTML(false)` and set only `Body` - don't put anything in `AltBody`.

There's no need to start from scratch every time - you can re-use the same PHPMailer instance and just change properties before sending for the second time.

You're using the submitters address as the From address - that's forgery, and will result in bounces from SPF failures, so put your address in From and theirs in reply-to.

As Jon says, validate, sanitize and escape anything going into SQL - it's quite likely that your failures are from submissions that contain a `'`, which will break your SQL.

Comment: Thanks for thorough answer.  What is the best way to sanitize and escape, in your opinion (I know there are lots of opinions out there).  Is mysqli_real_escape_string enough?  I use that for the textareas but Ill apply it to every field per your suggestion.

Comment: Escaping solves the majority, but it's much better if bad data is not allowed in in the first place. Try sanitising by applying `strip_tags` to any inputs that should not contain HTML, strip anything that's not allowed in a phone number from phone number fields, strip numbers and symbols from name fields, if a value should be one from a list (e.g. in an HTML select), check that it is etc. You can make this easier on the user by doing it client side as well (not instead of!); jQuery-validate is good for that.